# How to deploy create react app on my website?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web

So I have a website and I want to deploy some of my projects on my portfolio website like mywebsite.com/first-project.html

I already ran npm run build so I have a build version with the static files and I put it on my website but the react index.html isn't return anything the div id of root is empty.

I have seen tutorial of deploying them through surge and github pages. I don't want to do that, I want it on my own website. How can I achieve this?

Edit:- I forgot to mention the projects I created are through the npm create-react-app method and I have run the static build through serve -s build on my local computer. I just want to do the same on my website.

Edit2:- In the future if I am creating a react based website with the intention of hosting on my own domain, what kind of groundwork should I lay to make it easier? Any node packages or routing or set up? Also would you recommend create-react-app for this purpose if not what method would you recommend?

Comment: Please share your code/build settings. Try to run your build app local with HTTP-Server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). It's hard to find the problem with just a "description".

Comment: Had a similar case here, had to deploy a `create-react-app` app on my own server. I used capistrano for deployment (since I am also rails developer) and the process went like this: first I had to upload my whole project on a server, then run `npm install` and `npm run build`. What remained was to configure my server to always point to `index.html`